# Finding rows with decimal points and multiply them by 1000 - R

Tags: r

This is an example of the dataset

```
n | rbc
-------
1 | 2500
2 | 2.7
3 | 4500
```

I want to find rows that has decimal points and then multiply them by 1000

Comment: Can you share a sample data coming from `dput(your_df)`? If you have a vector of integer and doubles, then R coerces all numbers to be double (they all will have decimals), so the only way you get integer and numbers with decimal points is that they are stored as character. Run this `c(1,2,3.2)` and you'll get `[1] 1.0 2.0 3.2` as you can see all have decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with `grep`. Search for the dot regex, escaped since it is a meta-character. And subset the data with its return value.

```r
i <- grep('\\.', df1$rbc)
df1$rbc[i] <- df1$rbc[i] * 1000
df1
#>   n  rbc
#> 1 1 2500
#> 2 2 2700
#> 3 3 4500
#> 4 4    1
#> 5 5   18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To also multiply other small numbers by 1000 the following code should be used instead of the code above. `dig` is the number of digits of the numbers that are to be multiplied.

```r
dig <- 2L

i <- grepl('\\.', df1$rbc)
j <- nchar(df1$rbc) <= dig
df1$rbc[i | j] <- df1$rbc[i | j] * 1000
df1
#>   n   rbc
#> 1 1  2500
#> 2 2  2700
#> 3 3  4500
#> 4 4  1000
#> 5 5 18000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <-'n | rbc
1 | 2500
2 | 2.7
3 | 4500
4 | 1.0
5 | 18.0'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE, sep = '|')
str(df1)
#> 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ n  : num  1 2 3 4 5
#>  $ rbc: num  2500 2.7 4500 1 18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi! I use grep and it works. But I have issues with those without decimal points - ie 1.0, 18.0. could you help me with it?

Comment: @NabilHusni Do you want all numbers less than 3 digits to be multiplied by 1000?

Comment: Yup. To be exact, number who are less than 50 needs to be multiple by 1000. We changed the system half way during data collection

Comment: @NabilHusni So, with `dig <- 50` use `df1$rbc <= dig` instead .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all values in the `rbc` column are numeric and you only want to look for values between -1 and 1 in that column, then one trick would be to find rows where the integer part of `rbc` is zero and adjust only those values:

```
has_dec <- floor(abs(df$rbc)) == 0
df[has_dec, "rbc"] <- df[has_dec, "rbc"] * 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data are numeric, use the modulo operator (`%%`).

```
within(df, rbc <- rbc*(1 + ((rbc %% 1) > 0)*999))
#>   n  rbc
#> 1 1 2500
#> 2 2 2700
#> 3 3 4500
```